# Cassandra WordCount Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, cassandra

Can anyone explain to me the following lines from Cassandra 2.1.15 WordCount example?

```
CqlConfigHelper.setInputCQLPageRowSize(job.getConfiguration(), "3");
CqlConfigHelper.setInputCql(job.getConfiguration(), "select * from " + COLUMN_FAMILY + " where token(id) > ? and token(id) <= ? allow filtering");
```

How do I define concrete values which will be used to replace "?" in the query?

And what is meant by page row size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I define concrete values which will be used to replace "?" in
>   the query?

You don't. These parameterized values are set by the splits created by the input format. They are set automatically but can be adjusted (to a degree) by adjusting the split size.

> And what is meant by page row size?

Page row size determines the number of CQL Rows retrieved in a single request by a mapper during execution. If a C* partition contains 10000 CQL rows and the page row size is set to 1000, it will take 10 requests to retrieve all of the data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Sir, it is very good. But how do I define which rows do I want as input, by their key? I tried something like "select * from basketball where team='lakers' allow filtering" but I'm getting the following exception - Invalid amount of bind variables. I would like to select all rows that have for example 'lakers' as their name, how to do that?

Also, about the second part, does that mean that I'm implicitly defining number of Mappers? If I have 10 requests, will that mean that 10 map tasks will be created?

Comment: The input format takes the entire C* token range and divides it based on input split size. This makes a number of splits. Each split executes a query with two variables, start token and end token. This is why it demands that you ALWAYS must have 2 variables in your query. For your "Lakers" query you would just add on to the end something like  where token(partitionkeyname) > ? and token(partitionkeynameid) <= ?.

Comment: Can you please reconsider my question? The following query won't work "select * from basketball.nba where team='lakers' and token(team)>? and token(team)<=?", I guess that I have misunderstood something?

Comment: If that query does not work it is because it is not valid Cql. Your schema most likely will not allow that query because of the internal structure.  the error message should explain this. I would consider looking into more independent Cassandra data modeling before trying to write Hadoop jobs. Also you may just want to use hive or pig so that you don't have to work at this level of abstraction.

Comment: Here is the exception I get - com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Column "team" cannot be restricted by both an equality and an inequality relation - and I see no reason for that, team is the Partitioning key and I have also another Clustering column and another simple column. Are you sure that the CQL I wrote looks correct? What would be the approach to use setInputWhereClauses? I tried with (team="lakers"), but still not good.

Comment: if team is the partitioning key then it is also being restricted by the token argument from the split. Are you sure you need a hadoop job if you are only pulling a single partition?

Comment: You are absolutely right,it wouldn't make sense to use it for something like that. I'm trying out things and it seemed lije a logical thing to start with select and where. What I really need is IN, since I'm having a number of objects that I want to pool from Cassandra by their key. How wouls you suggest that in my case?